# Angular date-range-input fire change

Tags: angular, events

I have problem because I do not know how to fire a change event after someone picks a date.

My current code:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Wybierz przedział czasowy
      </mat-label>
      <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Data początkowa">
        <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="Data końcowa">
      </mat-date-range-input>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]=" picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

      <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Zła data początkowa</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Zła data końcowa</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem? @loczek

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can know when change in differents ways

using [(dataChange) or (dateInput)](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatStartDate) in each input:

```
<mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date" (dateChange)="startChange($event)">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date" (dateChange)="endChange($event)">
</mat-date-range-input>


startChange(event:MatDatepickerInputEvent)
  {
   console.log("startChange",event.value)
  }
  endChange(event:MatDatepickerInputEvent)
  {
   console.log("endChange",event.value)
  }
```

Of subscribing to valueChanges of the FormGroup/FormControl. e.g. in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.range.get('start').valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log("valueChange start",res)
    })
    this.range.get('end').valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log("valueChange end",res)
    })
    this.range.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log("range Change",res)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Your first solution is not working but second with subscribe is nice. Thanks for help !

Comment: @loczek,  an stackblitz using the first option: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ai7kcs